# Does std::move called on a prvalue deconstruct the object?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, rvalue, stdmove

I 've wrote such code applying `std::move` to a prvalue from a temporary constructor.

```cpp
  // a std::string instance in class Obj

  Obj&& myObj1 = std::move(Obj(1,"lost"));
  print(myObj1);

  Obj&& myObj2 = Obj(2,"keep");
  print(myObj2);
```

And the print effects is like that (`print` also in constructor and destructor):

```
Construct lost
Destroy lost
obj1: 

Construct keep
obj2: keep
Destroy keep
```

Some questions in stackoverflow say there should be no effect for the first case, I wonder what happens in my code. Is that the `Obj(1, "lost")` in the `std::move` function as argument and dies when `std::move` exit ?

Comment: `Obj(1,"lost")` _is_ an rvalue. `std::move` will cast it to an rvalue, so it's effectively a no-op. Please, post a [repro].

Comment: @Enlico Sorry, I have read the page and imitated other posts，in this case does it means I should provide a minimal compileable codes instead missing the detail？

Comment: Your code is not usable as it is. Make it such that one can copy, paste, compile, and run.

Comment: FYI The amount of code in the question is just fine to support the question.  It would be nice to have a compile-ready complete example in addition (some offsite location like github or pastebin is fine for compile-ready demos, since the question is still fully valid even if the link breaks).  The question would be substantially more difficult to read if it started with a full program instead of just the lines of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::move` is a function call; it's not a magical operator of C++. All it does is return a reference to the object it is given. And it takes its parameter by reference.

In C++, if you have a prvalue, and you pass it to a function that takes a reference to it, the temporary created by that prvalue will only persist until the end of the expression.

So `move` returns a reference to the temporary. But that temporary will be destroyed immediately after `myObj1` is initialized. So `myObj1` is a reference to a destroyed object.

Comment: @bloody: If a function takes a parameter by value, a prvalue (in C++17) does not create a temporary. It initializes the parameter directly. So only functions which take references will generate a temporary. The lifetime of by-value parameters works out to something similar, but they're not the same.

Comment: OK, Thanks for explanation. Btw. you could have clarified this after my first edition to avoid another edition/rejection/clicking and further confusion ;)